# Density of the universe

Tags: density

Why is the universe of the same uniform density at all distance and time scales? Why haven't cosmologists realised this simple fact disproves the big bang? Why do they keep pushing theories as accepted fact when many are hotly disputed and as in this case completely disproven by the data?

Why is the dissenting voice routinely attacked with vicious ad hominem attacks? Why is it that when dissidents in online astronomical courses refuse to back down they may get there accounts disabled?

The answer is clear and obvious.

The elite wish to separate us from reality and so weaken us spiritually and those at the "top" of their professions are today mostly puppets of the elite pushing whatever they are told to push. The truth in scientific circles is no longer of much relevance. They have become hopelessly politicised.

As a result most of modern cosmology consists of junk science being pushed by junk people.

Comment: Sounds like somebody has a grudge... but no physics question.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: "puppets of the elite" and "junk people"? Sounds like an ad hominem attack to me.

Answer (score 2):

Please study [Ned Wright's Cosmology FAQ: How do Astronomer's Measure the Density of the Universe?](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/density.html)

There it is pointed out that the local density varies from region to region; the scale of the region surveyed determines the granularity.

The answer is clear and obvious: the density of the universe is NOT uniform at all distance and time scales.

Comment: Not to mention the expansion of space, which makes the mean density decrease over time.

Comment: I am speaking of the large scale density. Not densities cherry picked to support a particular argument. Where is the evidence to the density decrease?

Comment: So once again I am presented with someone pushing anothers arguments which they show no evidence of understanding. Present me with the particualr points you want considered. I am not going to waste my time reading other peoples work that is pushed at me. This tactic is clear and understood. No such information will be presented as in all other exchanges as it cannot be. A person who understands an argument will speak of it, he who doesn't will refer to it.

Comment: So what happened to my comments? Am I immediately banned through speaking of a truth non wish to hear?

Comment: I got the response I expected. It is almost identical to all others. No where within the online astronomical community I have been are there people of worth capable of addressing an argument they have an emotional issue with.

My account or whatever with this site will be closed. Junk people pushing junk science at all levels of the field. All incapable of even considering the truth exists.